# Why am I getting a TypeError when I seem to be filling the paremeters?

Tags: python, object, typeerror

I am trying to create an object and I'm initializing it with 2 fields first (name & number). However each time I run the program I'm given this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'
```

The `__init__` method in the class looks like this:

```
    def __init__(self, name, number):
    self.__name__ = name
    self.__number__ = number
```

The code where I try to create the object is this:

```
employee1 = ProductionWorker(Employee)

name = input("Enter employee name:")
number = input("Enter employee number:")

employee1.__init__(name, number)
```

Does anyone know why I may be getting this error?

Comment: The `__init__` method requires two arguments: name and number. You only provided one argument in `employee1 = ProductionWorker(Employee)`

Comment: I thought I needed to add the info for the object employee1 after it was created. How would I fix that if it's the problem?

Comment: You should not be calling `__init__` explicitly.  `__init__` is called automatically by the interpreter when you instantiate the object (e.g. `ProductionWorker(name, number)`.)

Comment: You have some very basic misunderstandings here, you should reread your tutorial on Python OOP.

Comment: What is `ProductionWorker`? Please update your question with this missing detail.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. I see the issue you pointed out, and I'll make sure to review that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
name = input("Enter employee name:")
number = input("Enter employee number:")

employee1 = ProductionWorker(name, number)
```

You do not generally need to call `__init__` explicitly; it's invoked by the `ProductionWorker(...)` expression, which passes its arguments to `self.__init__` as part of initialization.

You do not need to restate when constructing a new object that `Employee` is the parent class; that only needs to be said when the class is defined.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed my issue I see how I was misunderstanding now

Answer (score 0):

You are using the class as a parameter.
Then, `init` is always automatically called on creation. This how it might work as You want (using the show method to validate):

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.__name__ = name
        self.__number__ = number
    

    def show(self):
        print(self.__name__)
        print(self.__number__)
    

name = input("Enter employee name:")
number = input("Enter employee number:")
employee1 = Employee(name,number)
employee1.show()
```